# Backend storage for Amazon CloudWatch Log Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

What could be the backend storage for Amazon CloudWatch Log Groups.

Is it an Amazon S3 backend?

Or is it a physical managed service that AWS manages?

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein That’s a general enquiry out of curiosity

Answer (score 0):

AWS has not exposed what backend the CloudWatch uses.
But if you are interested in doing it yourself.
You can create a StatsD backend for your applications.

https://github.com/camitz/aws-cloudwatch-statsd-backend